# How to override maven command line options for particular project?

Tags: maven

I need to pass specific system option for one of the maven plugins, that obtains if via `System.getProperty`.

It works fine when I run `mvn clean package -Dfoo=bar`, but I would like to somehow "preconfigure" this option to have it applied "automagically" just after cloning the repository.

Comment: Why not putting that into the pom file?

Comment: It doesn't work for me since this particular plugin reads System environment. Also the question is "How to override maven command line options?"

Comment: That sounds like a very bad plugin... not to handle configuration via pom file... ?? Can you name it?

Comment: Nope, this is very good plugin, that saved a lot of time for many people already. But the property I need to override is not a part of plugin's configuration. https://github.com/eclipse-tycho/tycho/blob/master/tycho-extras/tycho-pomless/src/main/java/org/eclipse/tycho/pomless/TychoAggregatorMapping.java#L46
Again, we can forget about plugin and focus on passing maven command line argument, like `-U` or whatever else.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to configure maven command line options using
`maven.config` file inside `.mvn` folder:

```
/
  .mvn/
    maven.config
  pom.xml
```

The content of `maven.config` for my case is:

```
-Dfoo=bar
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to add it to the `pom.xml` in the `<properties>` section, as khmarbaise said.

Comment: It doesn't work for me since this particular plugin reads System environment. Also the question is "How to override maven command line options?" and your answer is about overriding Maven properties.

Comment: @AlexanderFedorov Have you tried? I mean, `-Dfoo=bar` is also a Maven property. Which plugin are we talking about?

Comment: Yes, I did. I think the plugin is good, but the property I need to override is not a part of its configuration.

Comment: https://github.com/eclipse-tycho/tycho/blob/master/tycho-extras/tycho-pomless/src/main/java/org/eclipse/tycho/pomless/TychoAggregatorMapping.java#L46
Again, we can forget about plugin and focus on passing maven command line argument, like `-U` or whatever else.

Comment: @AlexanderFedorov So you actually put that properties into the `<properties>` section of the POM and it was not read by the plugin?

Comment: Yes, my first choice was to put property to the `<properties>`, and It doesn't work for me. Perhaps I did something wrong.